# Collect values of child tag using Python lxml

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I'm using the `lxml` library with Python 2.6 to extract data from an xml file. Within the document I have many `<Employee>` tags. I iterate over each `<Employee>` tag, create a new instance of my `Employee` class and set its member variables with the values of the `Employee` tag.

```
    read_CA_tree = etree.parse(xml_tree, parser)
    all_employees = []
    for employee_tag in read_CA_tree.iter("Employee"):
        employee = Employee(employee_tag)
        all_employees.append(employee)
```

The `<Employee>` tag may also have one or more `<EmailAddress>` child tags like so:

```
<Employee ID="124" Name="Foo Bar" Title="Baz">
   <EmailAddress ID="124" Address="foobar@fizzbang.com" />
 </Employee>
```

My Employee object is instantiated via lxml's `Element` calls `get()` method

```
class Employee(object):

    def __init__(self, employee_tag):
        self.Employee_ID = employee_tag.get("EmployeeID")
        self.First_Name = employee_tag.get("FirstName")
        self.Email_Addresses = self._collect_email(read_CA_tree, "EmailAddress")

    def _collect_emails(self,tree,tag):
        known_addr = []
        for i in tree.iter(tag):
            known_addr.append(i)
        return known_addr
```

For each `Employee` tag, how can I collect the value(s) of `Address` within the child `<EmailAddress>` tag and add a list of email addresses to my `Employee` class constructor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From the dox](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html):

> Elements carry attributes as a dict

So, you can try:

```
def _collect_emails(self,tree,tag):
    known_addr = []
    email_addr = []
    for i in tree.iter(tag):
        known_addr.append(i)
        email_addr.append(i.get('Address', '')
    return known_addr
```